# django apps and models.py in 1.7 - what exactly has changed?

Tags: django, django-models, django-apps

Django 1.7 has introduced some apparently major changes for how apps work

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#app-loading-refactor

These release notes seem to be saying that you can define models outside of `models.py` and we don't even need a `models.py` (or `models/__init__.py`) inside an app.

Am I misunderstanding this? If not, could someone explain where we define our models if they are not in `models.py` and how does django find and load them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still define your models in `models.py`.

Before the app refactor in 1.7 there wasn't a unified API for declaring metadata about your app. In particular, the way Django determined whether something was an app or not was by looking for a `models.py` file. That was not an elegant system, especially when you consider that some apps don't even have models (for example, the app might just provide management commands).

Now that the `AppConfig` API exists it's no longer necessary to require the existence of a `models.py`. However, it's still the natural, and default, place to define your models.

*How does django find and load them?*

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#how-applications-are-loaded): "You must define or import all models in your application’s `models.py` or `models/__init__.py`."

That suggests the following practice: if you don't have any models, don't include a `models.py`. If you have a file's worth of models, put them in `models.py`. If you have a bunch of models and want to spread them out over multiple files, put the files in a `models` submodule and import their contents in `models/__init__.py`.

Comment: Very helpful. I am still a bit confused by the fact that, according to the documentation, we *must* define all models in `models.py` (or import them with `models/__init__.py`), but that a `models.py` module is technically no longer necessary because of the `AppConfig` API. Can we now define models outside of `models.py` or `models/__init__.py`, even if it is unnatural to do so?

Comment: @mjandrews: You can define the models anywhere, but they must be imported by either `models.py` or `models/__init__.py`. That module name (`models`) is not a configurable parameter of the `AppConfig` API. The only time you won't have one of those files is if your app doesn't use models at all.